# Disable Tenacity for loop `for attempt in Retrying` in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-tenacity, tenacity

I am writing unit tests and want to disable tenacity, I've previously been able to disable tenacity when its a decorator ie:

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3),wait=wait_fixed(5))
def function_that_retries(param) -> None:
    <function implementation>
```

with:

```
    def test_function(self):
       # disable tenacity retry
       function.retry.retry = tenacity.retry_if_not_result(lambda x: True)
```

Now I want to disable this sort of tenacity for loop:

```
    @property
    def is_ready(self) -> bool:
        try:
            for attempt in Retrying(stop=stop_after_delay(60), wait=wait_fixed(3)):
                with attempt:
                    # The ping command is cheap and does not require auth.
                    self.client.admin.command("ping")
        except RetryError:
            return False

        return True
```

while mocking that `self.client.admin.command` raises a `ConnectionFailure` error (i.e. I don't want to get around this by raising a `RetryError` for the `self.client.admin.command`)

Right now my test looks like this

```
class TestMongoServer(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("lib.charms.mongodb_libs.v0.mongodb.MongoClient")
    @patch("lib.charms.mongodb_libs.v0.mongodb.MongoDBConfiguration")
    def test_is_ready_error_handling(self, config, mock_client):
        # TODO figure out how to disable tenacity for faster unit testing

        with MongoDBConnection(config) as mongo:
           mock_client.return_value.admin.command.side_effect = ConnectionFailure()

           #  verify ready is false when an error occurs
           ready = mongo.is_ready
           self.assertEqual(ready, False)

           # verify we close connection
           (mock_client.return_value.close).assert_called()
```

but it doesn't disable tenacity, whats the correct way to disable tenacity when its used with `for attempt in Retrying`?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to include tenacity for your test.
just mock sleep of tenacity like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def tenacity_wait(mocker):
    mocker.patch('tenacity.nap.time')
```

You can add this to conftest.py in the root folder of unit test.